# Why curly braces and dollar used in this return statement?

Tags: javascript

In code why following line is used, since it's not creating emails from collection list.

Ambiguous Code Line: "return `{$item}$@{ this.domain }`"

```
var object = {

    collection: ["kapil", "abdul", "shiv"],
    domain: 'infobeans.com',
    method: function method() {
        return this.collection.map(item => {
            //return item + '@' + this.domain;
            return `{$item}$@{ this.domain }`
        });
    }
};

console.log(object.method());
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: you know what that return statement will return? ... `{$item}$@{ this.domain }` ... perhaps you mean `${item}@${this.domain}`

Comment: I am wathcing ES2015 tutorials and it's working there but when i tried same thing on my local it's just printing expression in console. That's why i created this question. What can be a reason for this ?

Comment: because you've swapped { an $, and later, $ and @ - thinking the order is unimportant - see the correct order and how it works as advertised

Answer (score 1):

```
var object = {

    collection: ["kapil", "abdul", "shiv"],
    domain: 'infobeans.com',
    method: function method() {
        return this.collection.map(item => {
            //return item + '@' + this.domain;
            return `${item}@${ this.domain }`
        });
    }
};

console.log("object.method",object.method());
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I got it. $ needs to be outside of {} braces.